# Choosing a Close Reason

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

What close reason should I choose for a question like [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/617894/)?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like

> #### Needs details or clarity
>
> This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

applies, as it's (to me) completely unclear what the author is asking. It might be that the question is still off-topic even after it's improved, but more clarification is step one. Meanwhile, a ♦ moderator with a crystal ball chose a custom off-topic close reason, which is also fine. The chance that this question, after some edits, turns out to be worthwhile to migrate to another site, is very small.